# install numpy on python 3.5 Mac OS High sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy

I wanted to install the numpy package for python 3.5 on my Mac OS High Sierra, but I can't seem to make it work.

I have it on python2.7, but I would also like to install it for the next versions.

Currently, I have installed `python 2.7`, `python 3.5`, and `python 3.7`.

I tried to install `numpy` using:

- `brew install numpy --with-python3` (no error)
- `sudo port install py35-numpy@1.15.4` (no error)
- `sudo port install py37-numpy@1.15.4` (no error)
- `pip3.5  install numpy` (gives "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for numpy" )

I can tell that it is not installed because when I type `python3` and then `import numpy as np` gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'"

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use Anaconda to install python or homebrew?

Comment: The above comment should read "did you use Anaconda or homebrew to install python on your machine"?

Comment: I think that python 2.7 was already pre-installed, about the next versions of python I honestly don't remember having installed them, they probably came with some other package. I did try to do install python3 with brew, but numpy is still not seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to activate the virtual environment for the version of python you wish to run. After you have done that then just run "pip install numpy" or "pip3 install numpy".

If you used Anaconda to install python then, after activating your environment, type conda install numpy.

Comment: I don't have Anaconda. How do you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: I also noticed that typing `pip --version` gives  "/usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: no such file or directory", while pip3.5 seems to work (but does not find any package at all). Shouldn't it be better to uninstall everything and reinstall again?

Comment: If you have more than one version of python you should set up virtual environments.  There are instructions on the internet on how to create virtual environments. i used Anaconda which makes virtual environments easier so I don't know how to do it on a non-Anaconda machine.  But the instructions on the internet should guide you thru.

Comment: After installing anaconda, everything worked perfectly.I didn't even had to modify any setting or install packages.

Answer (score 0):

If running `pip3.5 --version` or `pip3 --version` works, what is the output when you run `pip3 freeze`? If there is no output, it indicates that there are no packages installed for the Python 3 environment and you should be able to install numpy with `pip3 install numpy`.